# How to properly recursively chown files (including hidden dirs)

Tags: linux, chown

This conundrum is caused by running `git pull` from root.

There are various reasons for me to do so... I want my device to update code when booting up, and `rc.local` is run by root.

It all works mostly fine (`npm install` tends to fail when run by root, but that's a whole 'nother topic), the problem arises when I try to use the git repository with a non-root user afterward... some of the git files have been written by root, so now I can't use it anymore (permission denied).

So I'd like to recursively `chown` it back but there doesn't seem to be anything that really works on all of the little git files. I tried the `-R` flag and `./**/*` path.

My guess is that neither of those techniques descend into dot-directories.

Comment: What shell are you using? In `bash` you need to set `shopt -s dotglob` in order to match hidden files by `*` or `**`.

Comment: @jimmij good to know, thanks (you can probably put that as an answer)

Comment: Did you `chown -R *`, instead of `chown -R .`?

Answer (score 18):

The following command works for me in Ubuntu. It changed all the files and directories ownership recusively

```
sudo chown -R someuser:somegroup YourDir
```

Comment: I tried `sudo chown -R me:me .` and when I `ls -al` all my files are still owned by root. Why does this not work?

Comment: @Richard did you try using an absolute path or `./` ?

Answer (score 0):

I use `tree` instead:

```
 sudo tree -fai ~/.blabla  | xargs -L1 -I{} sudo chown youruser:youruser {}
```

Also take care to not run recursive chown or chmod on '/' directory or other system directory.